# Jenkins + Maven - How to execute shell script before release:perform cleans the project

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I have a Maven project that generates a zip file with maven-assembly-plugin on mvn package

```
MyProy
|--pom
|--src/...
|--target
     |---MyProy-something-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-zip (contains /1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/...)
```

I created a Jenkins job and configured a shell script execution as a post step. This script copies the zip to a folder (/something) and unzips it

```
|-/something
     |---1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
             |---...
```

This works fine for builds. However I want to do the same when I launch a release. I installed Jenkins release plugin and in "configure release build" I added this tasks:

1. Before release build -> Maven task `mvn release:prepare`
2. After successful release build -> Maven task `mvn release:perform`
3. After successful release build -> Execute shell script - Copy zip and unzip.

I see the `mvn release:perform` execute correctly, for instance with version 1.0.0 but the problem is that when the script (3.) is launched it applies to the next development version (1.0.1-SNAPSHOT) instead of the release version (1.0.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to work around the problem:

1. **Before release build**

   1. mvn release:prepare
2. **After successful release build**

   1. mvn release:perform
   2. mvc scm:checkout -DscmVersion=${releaseVersion} -DscmVersionType=tag
   3. -f ${WORKSPACE}/target/checkout clean install
   4. Execute shell script with copy and unzip

To sum up, after the release:perform I checkout the brand new tag, execute a clean install in the location of the downloaded tag and finally I execute the script that copies the zip and unzipes it.

Comment: where to config: execute shell script after release build?